How to integrate the following $2$ integrals?
How to integrate :
$$1)\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+5[x+\sqrt{3}]+3]dx$$
$$2)\int_{1}^{2}[[x^{2}]+5[x+\sqrt{3}]+3]dx$$
Where $[.]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function.
The $1^{st}$ integral is very easy and I have done it. Let me explain:
$1)\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+5[x+\sqrt{3}]+3]dx=\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+3]dx+5\int_{0}^{1}[x+\sqrt{3}]dx=3+5\int_{0}^{2-\sqrt{3}}[x+\sqrt{3}]dx+5\int_{2-\sqrt{3}}^{1}[x+\sqrt{3}]dx=3+5(2-\sqrt{3})+10(\sqrt{3}-1)=5\sqrt{3}+3$
But I am unable to solve the $2^{nd}$ one. Because the limits are from $1$ to $2$. And $\int_{1}^{2}[x^{2}]\neq 1$.
Please help me out with the $2^{nd}$ integral.

Acording to wolframalpha the first integral is equal to $5\sqrt{3}+9$.

Your computations for $1)$ works if $[\cdot ]$ is the lowest integer function instead of the greatest.

I think you are using greatest integer function as the greatest integer less than its argument.  We usually call that the floor function and use \lfloor and \rfloor as brackets to indicate it, so the floor of x would be written \lfloor x \rfloor and look like $\lfloor x \rfloor$

You can use the same approach as you did for the first integral for all the terms except $\int_1^2 \lfloor x^2\rfloor dx$, which you can split into pieces in $x$ where the floor changes.  The points are $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$, so
$$\int_1^2 \lfloor x^2\rfloor dx=\int_1^{\sqrt 2}1 dx + \int_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 3}2dx+\int_{\sqrt 3}^23dx=1(\sqrt 2-1)+2(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2)+3(2-\sqrt 3)$$

I guess that you mean to use $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ instead of $[\cdot]$ ?
You need to break the functions into parts in order to integrate them :
1)
$$\left \lfloor x^2+5 \left \lfloor x+\sqrt{3} \right \rfloor +3 \right \rfloor
=
\begin{cases}
8 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ 0, 2-\sqrt{3} \right[\\
13 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ 2-\sqrt{3}, 1 \right[ \\
14 & \text{if} & x =1
\end{cases}$$
2)
$$\left \lfloor \left \lfloor x^2 \right \rfloor + 5\left \lfloor x+\sqrt{3} \right \rfloor +3 \right \rfloor=
\begin{cases}
14 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ 1, 3-\sqrt{3} \right[ \\
19 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ 3-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}\right[ \\
20 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\right[ \\
21 & \text{if} & x \in \left[ \sqrt{3}, 2\right[ \\
22 & \text{if} & x =2
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from there ?

How you found the numbers $3-\sqrt{3}$ , $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$ ?

@IITRoorkee The image of the function $x \mapsto x + \sqrt{3}$ on the interval $[1,2]$ is the interval $\left[1+\sqrt{3},2+\sqrt{3}\right]$. You get the following inequality :
$$ x + \sqrt{3}<3 \Longleftrightarrow x<3-\sqrt{3}$$
Which means that
$$
\left \lfloor x + \sqrt{3} \right \rfloor=
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if} & x  \in \left[ 1,3-\sqrt{3} \right[ \
3 &  \text{if} & x  \in \left[ 3-\sqrt{3},2 \right[
\end{cases}
$$

@IITRoorkee Other than that
$$
\left \lfloor x^2 \right \rfloor=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if} & x  \in \left[ 1,\sqrt{2} \right[ \
2 &  \text{if} & x  \in \left[ \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3} \right[ \
3 &  \text{if} & x  \in \left[ \sqrt{3},2 \right[ \
4 &  \text{if} & x  = 2
\end{cases}
$$


Splitting the integral into 3 pieces yield
$$
I_2=\int_1^2\left[x^2\right] d x+5 \int_1^2[x+\sqrt{3}]+\int_1^2 3 d x
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^{2}\left[x^2\right] d x& =\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\left[x^2\right] d x+\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}}\left[x^2\right] d x+\int_{\sqrt{3}}^2\left[x^2\right] d x \\
& =1(\sqrt{2}-1)+2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+3(2-\sqrt{3})\\&=5-\sqrt 2-\sqrt3
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^{2}[x+\sqrt{3}] d x& =\int_1^{3-\sqrt{3}}[x+\sqrt{3}] d x+\int_{3-\sqrt{3}}^2[x+\sqrt{3}] dx \\
& =2(3-\sqrt{3}-1)+3[2-(3-\sqrt{3})]\\&=1+\sqrt3
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back gives
$$\boxed{I_2= 5-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}+5(1+\sqrt{3})+3=13-\sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3} }$$

